# How to get \autoref labels right with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, luatex, polyglossia

As of late, I switched from `pdflatex` to `luatex`. I took an example file from the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX#Aufbau_eines_Dokuments) and compiled it without error (TeXlive 2016 btw).
Now, I noticed that when employing `\autoref`, which I'm quite used to, the labels are printed in English instead of German, albeit I `\setdefaultlanguage` to German!
I've composed the following MWE to demonstrate this behavior:

```
%% MWE to show a problem with \autoref in LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\parindent0mm
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Formeln zur Berechnung der Masse der Alpen}
\author{Otto Normalverbraucher}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Es geht los mit der ersten Gleichung.
\begin{equation}
M_l c_l \diff{T_B}{t} = 
-h_{int} A (T_B - T_E) - \dot{M}_l c_l (T_B - T_{amb})
\end{equation}

Danach folgt \autoref{eq:wandbilanz}.
\begin{align}
M_E c_E \diff{T_E}{t} &= h_{int} A (T_B - T_E) - h_{rain} A (T_E - T_{rain}) + \rho_B \dot{V}_{cond} \Delta h_{cond} \label{eq:wandbilanz} \\
\dot{V}_{cond} &= \beta [ y_{vap}(T_B) - y_{vap}(T_E) ] A
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that the date is printed correctly in the German notation, but then it gives "Equation 2" instead of "Gleichung 2". Any idea how to fix this?
[image: PDF output of the MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of to the problem you've identified is to add the option

```
ngerman
```

to the list of options of the `\documentclass` instruction. Thus, you should write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
```

Alternatively, you could elect to load the `babel` package (with the lagnuage option `ngerman`, of course) instead of the `polyglossia` package. That way, you'd also get "Gleichung" instead of "equation"  as the label associated with the counter `equation`.

Comment: One can also add the language option to the hyperref options (\usepackage[german]{hyperref})

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. By setting the document class-wide option `ngerman` or `german` -- the OP had specified the `polyglossia` option `spelling=new`, which leads me to believe he/she is more interested in `ngerman` than in `german`... -- the language option is automatically passed to the `hyperref` package (and to all other packages too, whether or not they do something with this option...). Setting the language option at the document class level may be advantageous if the OP loads other language-aware packages in addition to `hyperref`-- say, `cleveref`.

Comment: Great, it works; I just thought that with `lualatex`, one should use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`!?

Comment: @rotton - Nowadays, one can use both `babel` and `polyglossia` with LuaLaTeX. Which package to choose should depend mainly on the language-specific support offered by the packages, for the language(s) you use in your document.